# Ambient Occlusion Bake problem smooth

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I'm stuck in a problem for last few days with my project. My AO bake isn't very smooth. When I increase the size of the UV island, the error gets smaller, but it does not go away. I tried increasing the island margin and bake margin, but neither works.

[image: 3D View]
[image: UV Image Editor]

My *uv map* is 2048px and my project does not contain many faces.

Here are my settings:

- AO Factor: 0.10 ADD
- Environment Light: 1.0 (White)
- Gather Raytrace,
- Attenuation: 10.000,
- Falloff: 1.000,
- Constant QMC: 12 Samples (I have changed this value many times but got the same result)

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! You are saying the texture is 2048, but how much surface does the interested part cover? Can you show the whole UV space?

Comment: When a increase the size of the face in UV Space the problem gets smaller. https://image.prntscr.com/image/R9LzvqTKTSi_inN0r2zb8Q.png

Comment: So it looks like it's only a resolution issue.

Comment: Yeah, i think it is but i can't increase the size of my resolution and my project is not much high polly, to have big resolution size. I think i need to find another way to discrease this problems. And i will try a 4048px resolution.

Comment: You can also try to optimze your UV layout in order to give to the more meaningful faces the resolution they need. Without other information about your specific project, I can't tell you more than this.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking this, i will try to reduce this problem.

Comment: Have you also tried out baking AO with cycles? IMHO much better quality. ;)

Comment: You could  sidestep the problem by editing the AO map to lighten those black areas

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to Boolean your intersecting pieces together:

[image: bake]

Comment: It didn't work, a put the modifier Boolean diferrence but the same result.

Comment: @Augusto - Did you apply the modifier?  If not the geometry (and presumably the UVs) will be the same as before.  I have not checked to see, but I would not expect this to work until you actually apply and make permanent the boolean modifier.

Comment: Yeah, i apply the modifier.